# Listview can not scroll in tabview ? (Flutter)

Tags: listview, flutter, tabview

I have a tabview:

```
   TabBarView(
                  physics: FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
                  controller: _tabController,
                  children: [
                    ProfileTab(_scaffoldKey),
                    HistoryTab(_scaffoldKey),
                    LocationTab(_scaffoldKey),
                  ]),
            ])
```

I have a list view builder:

```
ListView.builder(
                    key: PageStorageKey("requests_history"),
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                    itemCount: value.selecteds.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      HistoryRequest request = value.selecteds[index];
                      return Card(
                        child: ExpansionTile(
                          leading: Text("${request.status}"),
                          title: Text("${request.content}"),
                          trailing: Text("${request.date}"),
                        ),
                      );
                    })
```

My problem is I can not scroll when I'm in the middle tab. Can somebody give me an advice?